# How to print a specific word in a text file in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, if-statement

so as you can see i have a text file that goes like this one:

unbelievable, un, believe, able
mistreatment, mis, treat, ment
understandable, understand, able

I need to get the morphemes or each word like for example if I typed in the word MISTREATMENT, the output would be MIS, TREAT, MENT and the root word is TREAT.

Here's my code so far:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class morph {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

         System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
         Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
         sc.nextLine();

         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/morphemes.txt"));
         String line = null;
         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

             //i'm stuck

             System.out.println("The morpheme words are: "); // EG: mis , treat, ment
             System.out.println("The Root word is: "); // EG: treat
         }
    }
}
```

The output should be:

Enter a word: mistreatment
The morpheme words: mis, treat, ment
The root word is: treat

The question is how do i print a specific data in the text file. I don't know i am gonna use an if else statement or a dictionary. If you're gonna tell me that it should be a dictionary please help me out. This is an NLP topic btw

Comment: What's your problem you need help with? Do you expect us to write the code?

Comment: You ask us to search for a specific algorithm or library that solves this issue. Please note that such questions are often considered as **off-topic** on SO. Maybe you find better help at [CS stackexchange](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Your "code so far" is not a real attempt to solve the problem. Requests for code are not questions. Please research this subject and read the [help] and [ask] before posting a question.

Comment: @PakerHalo how to make that dictionary?

Comment: @PakerHalo how to make that dictionary? what specific topic should i research to get it? It's so hard to find so i'm looking if there's a way other than the dictionary like maybe if-else or arrays will do

Comment: @TheRodDude What do you need help With? Creating the Dictionary from the file? I assume the file already contain the lines you provided?

Answer (score -1):

I guess the method String.split() can help you here.

```
public String[] words = line.split(String ",");

// Check if first word in the line equals to the input
if (words != null && !words.isEmpty() && words[0].equals(sc.toString()))
{ 
  System.out.println("The morpheme words are: "+words[1]+words[2]);
  System.out.println("The Root word is: "+words[2]);
}
```

Comment: Above he claims to have a text file with the morphemes ?!?

Comment: Yes the words are saved in the text file so the user has to input one of those words and the program should get its morphemes. I really can't find help on the internet since it's an NLP topic

Comment: Right - there is no way I can think of to create the morphemes. Sorry - then I understood "I HAVE a text file" wrong. I assumed this file is existing- whoever filled it....

Comment: yeah our professor suggested to have that 'dictionary' but i really have no idea what that is so i bet there's an easier way